# How to do I get PHP and MySQL to return an integer using the MAX() function?

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

I have a database with a column of only numbers and i need to use php to access it and use the MAX() function to get the largest number, when i use the max function and then try to "echo" the value it says it isn't a string but an object. How would i fix this?

```
    $nextnumber=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(videonumber) AS maxnum FROM videos");

    echo ($maxnum);
```

Comment: In these 2 lines `$maxnum` variable isn't even defined.

Comment: user2555310 How have others tackled similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

fetch the row/object from $nextnumber and then print the associated value with maxmum. For an example,

```
$nextnumber=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(videonumber) AS maxnum FROM videos");
$row = $nextnumber->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['maxnum'];
```

Comment: this is broken, as $maxnum is not defined in step 3 -- ps: was broken, you fixed it in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

mysqli returns a result object, you need to extract the value from there:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

i suggest you use `fetch_assoc()` to get it with the expected name

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

then you can access the value by name and print it:

```
echo($row["maxnum"])
```